# Can I use Xfire with SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot, xfire

My application uses Xfire as a web service client, It a legacy system where service is written in Perl, I am modifying/rewriting application with Spring boot, when I add the Maven dependency, it shows error when I try to build

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-aegis</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>            
        </dependency>
```

[ERROR] contextLoads(com.au.cis.IPND.IpndApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseType
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseType
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseType
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'

I don't know where database has been used

Comment: can you post full pom.xml dependencies

Comment: You are using Spring Boot but judging from the error don't use the starters or manage the dependencies properly. Also you probably will/might run into issues with `xfire-spring` as that is build for an older version of Spring and you  might encounter issues with the XFire Spring integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EmbeddedDatabaseType is part of spring-jdbc, so I would suggest adding the following dependency (if you do not already have it):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Please do adjust the version number (5.2.1.RELEASE) to match your other Spring dependencies!

Comment: hi, I added this and it worked, thank you, now rest of the challenge is making Xfire client work on Spring boot